# How do I mock Classes with Scala 3.2, Scalatest 3.2, and Java 18

Tags: java, scala, scalatest, easymock

I have the following code...

```scala
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IdentitySuite extends AnyFunSuite with Matchers {
  test("No Records returned") {
    assert(true)
  }
}
```

This works fine now I would like to add a mocked Object so I add...

```
testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use JUnit4 test framework
            useJUnit('4.13.2')
            dependencies {
                // Use Scalatest for testing our library
                implementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_3:3.2.12'
                implementation 'org.scalatestplus:junit-4-13_3:3.2.12.0'
                implementation 'org.easymock:easymock:4.3'
                implementation 'org.scalatestplus:easymock-4-3_3:3.2.12.0'
                runtimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_3:2.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to add the mock

```scala
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IdentitySuite extends AnyFunSuite with Matchers {
  test("No Records returned") {
    val cds = EasyMock.createMock(classOf[CoreDataSource])
    assert(true)
  }
}
```

I get

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @40f9161a

I see some old questions that point at downgrading to 15 but that isn't an option in my case.

How do I Mock a Scala class when using Java 18?

Comment: Scala's isn't friendly to Java approach to mocking (all methods non final, etc). There is Scala mock for this reason, but it is implemented using macros, so it has to be rewritten from scratch. Currently there is an issue for Scala 3 support on GH. For now you can create mocks manually.